How do you find the amount of noise or variation in a block of an audio signal

Considering the two patterns shown above I would like to create a noise factor using python that shows how noisy the pattern is. For example it may return 0.1 for smooth pattern but 0.6 for noisy one. I can think of some possibilities

Number of peaks and valleys
Number of sharp angles
May be combine both

